# Connecting to Mongodb using SSRS

Tags: mongodb, ssrs-2012, mongodb-.net-driver

In my requirement we need to show mongo database data in a report using SSRS. Could you please advise me the best way to connect to Mongo database using SSRS.

Comment: Look at ODBC drivers such as the page here. https://docs.mongodb.com/bi-connector/master/reference/odbc-driver
  You will probably have to install this on both your development PC and the SSRS server

Comment: Thank you Alan Schofield. Is their any way i can install and test it in my local..?

Comment: Sorry, I don't know but I suspect it will explain this in the documentation on the mongodb site.

Comment: I tried the steps mentioned in the above reference. Facing issue while creating the DNS for mongodb , once I enter  TCP port, UserId and password click on ok it is going to not responding mode. Do you have any thought to resolve this issue ?

Comment: I've never used mondodb, I just did a quick serach and found that